# End Row In Worksheet using ExcelPackage class library

Tags: vb.net, openoffice.org

I have a spreadsheet with many worksheets in it.  Each worksheet has a few column headers on the first row.  A user can add rows to these worksheets, and these rows get processed in my VB app by using the

```
workSheet.Dimension.End.Row
```

to get the range on that worksheet and looping through..  simple enough.  My problem is that if there are for example 3 rows on the first worksheet previously saved and the user opens the file, deletes the content (Not the whole row) of the row by highlighting the cells with data and pressing delete the above code still finds that there are 3 rows, even though there is no visible data.  If I of course delete the entire rows and not just the content then the code correctly calculates the rows and my app processes correctly.  I do not want the user to have to delete like that as they will forget of course, cannot blame them.  Is there a way of ensuring the last row using that code is actually the last row.  I guess I could loop through the rows to check each cell is empty but I wonder if there is any other way.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but as always as soon as I post here I find the answer..

[how to get EPPlus OpenXML row count (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400315/how-to-get-epplus-openxml-row-count-c) answers my problem perfectly using this code

```
var lastRow = sheet.Cells.Where(cell => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty)).LastOrDefault().End.Row;
```