# Using EPPlus without excel installed

Tags: excel

I am using EPPlus for excel report generation for automation using visual studio.I faced an issue that, it is difficult to get the used excel range row and column count. When i tried with `worksheet.Dimension.End.Row` and `worksheet.Dimension.End.Column` it is showing around a million rows and 16k columns.

Is there any other way to find out used range using EPPlus openxml? Is there any package which supports excel report generation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# EPPlus OpenXML count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777128/c-sharp-epplus-openxml-count-rows)